# Creating a USB tunnel to connect to a dongle

Tags: c++, c, linux, amazon-ec2, usb

I want to run software that is protected with a dongle on a cloud instance, for example EC2. I am NOT trying to circumvent the protection, but would like to set up a tunnel between a physical machine to which the dongle is connected and the USB driver in the cloud instance.

The software is built for Windows but runs well under Linux and Mac OS using Wine so from both sides running linux would be OK.

Would this be possible without writing a USB driver?
If yes, how do I set this up?
If not, how would I go about? I am a professional C/C++ developer but have no experience with driver development.

Comment: Before doing this, you should probably research if it's supported to do so according to the protected software's license. If it's OK, then the vendor should be able to help you, I would think.

Comment: There is no mention of anything related to this in the licence, so I can do it. Also, the solution I am after must be generic, a USB tunnel, it doesn't matter what data passes through it. So it has nothing to do with vendor specific details. Under *nix a USB device is a file of course, so I am wondering whether I can tunnel or pipe the file in the EC2 instance to the file on the physical machine.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by investigating existing commercial products that do this, such as (first search hit, no special endorsement or uniqueness implied) [USB over Network](http://www.usb-over-network.com/). They seem to solve almost exactly this problem, but for Windows clients.

On the Linux-specific side, we have [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) which seems to be an open source project to implement sharing of USB devices over IP networks. Again, no endorsement, I don't know how mature this project is but it seems to be the obvious starting point, perhaps you can even contribute?

Comment: Thanks very much, that is exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand why I didn't find these projects, as I spent quite some time googling myself. But again, thanks!